# Using != buk in AVAudioSession. currentroute in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, routes, swift2, avaudiosession

I am getting error Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type '[AVAudioSessionPortDescription]'   and 'NilLiteralConvertible in Swift 2 , this was fine until Swift 1
The program checks if headphone cable is plugged in or not

```
var currentRoute = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute 

 if currentRoute.outputs != nil {

                for description in currentRoute.outputs {
                    if description.portType ==

                        AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones {
                        print("headphone plugged in")
                        auximage.image=on

                    } else {
                        print("headphone pulled out")

                        auximage.image=off
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("requires connection to device")
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentRoute` and `outputs` are both non-null. You can simply do

```
for output in currentRoute.outputs {
```

and nothing else.